# How to authenticate users sending a job through Livy on a Dataproc Cluster without Kerberos

Tags: apache, security, authentication, kerberos, livy

We are trying to restrict users from sending a job to data proc cluster through livy server.

By default livy submits job as user 'livy' when impersonation is disabled. Even after using impersonation, it says livy is not allowed to impersonate user 'xxxx'.

Here, IAM policy of GCP is not useful either. Is there any way we can achieve this without kerberos?

Comment: Hi Prar Shah, were you able to find some lead/s about this?

Comment: @JoshuaVillanueva https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.5.6/bk_command-line-installation/content/grant_livy_impersonate.html